# C++ cout not displaying anything

Tags: c++, vector, cout

What may explain why the cout is not displaying anything in this code? I know it's related to the line v[0] = 1; but I can't find out why, does someone have an explanation for it?

Edit: I also know that changing v[0] = 1; for v.push_back(1); would solve the problem.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> v; 
    v[0] = 1; 
    cout << "Hello" << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Because the computer never gets to that line, because the program crashed on the previous line.

Comment: Sorry that was just a bad copy/paste, that is not the reason.

Comment: As soon as you've invoked undefined behavior the rest of your program is indeterminate.

Comment: *What* was a bad copy/paste?

Comment: First line was include <iostream> instead of #include <iostream>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `v[0]=1` because you haven't said how many elements the vector `v` has. So it causes run time error(it crashes)

Declare it as `vector<int>v(10)` (this says that `v` will have 10 elements)
and use `v[0]=1`

Or

If you don't know the vector size beforehand use `v.push_back(1);`

Comment: How would you explain why does the compiler not complain about it?

Comment: It does not check for `outofbound` access. It causes Undefined Behavior

Answer (score 3):

This code line

```
v[0] = 1;
```

actually calls undefined behavior, because the memory associated with this address wasn't allocated.

You preceed this line with e.g.

```
v.resize(1);
v[0] = 1;
```

to ensure the vector item is allocated.

---

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    vector<int> v; 
    v.resize(1);
    // alternatively 
    // vector<int> v(1);

    // alternatively 
    // v.push_back(0);
    v[0] = 1; 
    cout << "Hello" << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

See the [fully working sample](http://ideone.com/Vjt2qB).